# my code gives me a tuple error and i dont know why

Tags: python

## MAIN CODE

1. i dont really know why i keep on getting tuple errors the code looks fine
2. its just the loop part of my game for now, this is it

```
        import pygame 
    
    
    # important window variables
    WIDTH, HEIGHT = 900, 500
    
    WIN = WIDTH, HEIGHT
    
    SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIN))
    
    pygame.display.set_caption('SPACE GAME')
    
    WHITE = (0,0,0)
    
    # display function (what shows up on the screen)
    def display():
        WIN.fill(WHITE)
        pygame.display.update()
    
    
    # main function/loop function
    def main():
        run = True
        while run:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    run = False
    
            display()
        pygame.quit()
    
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Comment: Where is main?? I only see display() function

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post the full error along with the line number, etc.

Comment: I noticed that you set ```WIN = WIDTH, HEIGHT``` and then in the ```display()``` you do ```WIN.fill(WHITE)```.  I think this is the error.   ```WIN``` is a tuple.  It doesn't have a ```fill``` method.  Shouldn't it be ```SCREEN.fill(WHITE)```?

Comment: Hi Nabeel, welcome.  I believe you have the answer from @ewong, but as an aside: Because the color is a tuple of three integers, they are encoded as RGB, or (R, G, B) where each is a val from 0 to 255.
White should be (255, 255, 255) and black is (0, 0, 0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm confident this is the issue (though without the real error traceback, I could be wrong.)

The basic issue is that you set the value of `WIN` as a tuple
i.e.
`WIN = BASE, HEIGHT`

Then in the `display()` function, you do the following:

```
  WIN.fill(WHITE)
```

Which is what I think the error is.  `WIN` being a tuple,
has no `fill` method.  What I think you wanted to use is
`SCREEN.fill(WHITE)`

I took a gander at the documentation (as I don't know pygame),
and it confirms that: `pygame.display.set_mode((WIN))`
returns a `Surface` object which *does* have a `fill()`
method.

So, in conclusion:

```
    # important window variables
    WIDTH, HEIGHT = 900, 500
    
    WIN = WIDTH, HEIGHT
    
    SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIN))
    
    pygame.display.set_caption('SPACE GAME')
    
    WHITE = (0,0,0)
    
    # display function (what shows up on the screen)
    def display():
        SCREEN.fill(WHITE)
        pygame.display.update()
    
    
    # main function/loop function
    def main():
        run = True
        while run:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    run = False
    
            display()
        pygame.quit()
    
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```